# JavaScript: Load webpage with JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

Lets say I'm on a webpage `abc.com/xyz/` and I need the source code of `abc.com/xyz?param=true` to access a variable, that is not existing without that parameter, as this page relies heavily on JavaScript.

I'm building a Bookmarklet that shows this specific variable and my current workaround is to simply redirect the user with `location.href = page + "?param=true"`, where `page` is the current site and then instruct them to click again on this Bookmarklet (not user-friendly). If this parameter exists, I can access the variable.

To optimize this I want to load this second webpage in the background with vanilla JS or jQuery (as it's already used by `abc.com`) but using for e.g. `$.get()` will show only the webpage with JavaScript disabled.

tl;dr: How can I load another webpage with JS/jQuery and JavaScript enabled/executed?

Edit:
Some pseudo-code

```
javascript:(function() {

    var page = window.location.href;

    if(abc.com/.../ AND param=true) {
        var variable = document.getElementById("my_var");
        // do something with variable

    } else if(only abc.com/.../) {
        alert("Redirecting...");
        location.href = page + "?param=true";
    }
})();
```

Comment: Read this 3 times and still confused what the specific problem is and what you are trying to do. Can you clarify that these are pages you have no control over? Either way still confused about purpose of loading second page

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, it's not my native language :D
I need a variable that is only available if a parameter is set. That's why I need this "second" page with parameter to access the variable.
I don't have control over this/these page(s).

Comment: Not having a problem understanding language, you are doing fine there... it is hard to understand the overall problem. Show some code that helps represent the problem

Comment: @charlietfl added some pseudo-code

Comment: OK but why must you redirect if param isn't there? This is all bookmarklet code correct?

Comment: @charlietfl I need to redirect, because `document.getElementById("my_var")` only exists, if this param is there.

Procedure is like "User is on page abc.com; User clicks on the bookmarklet; param not there; redirect to page with param; User clicks again; param is now there; can access element in source code"

Yes, all bookmarklet code.

Comment: I do not understand your goal, but you can do this [I won't do it :)] by loading your page in an iframe, js will run just fine, and access your variable from parent page this way: var myVar = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.refVariable;

Comment: Forgot to say that my problem is, that I can't load a page in background (while staying on abc.com) with JS enabled. If I load it with jQuery, I only get the source code with JS disabled and all <noscript> tags.

@PaunNarcisIulian Also thought about this, even though it's a pretty dirty solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that checks for the presence of "param=true" in the request string and either appends the param (if not present) or allows for other actions if present:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function checkParam() {
    let page = window.location.href;
    if (page.indexOf('?param=true') < 0 && page.indexOf('&param=true') < 0) {
        if (page.indexOf('?') > 0) {
            window.location.href = page + '&param=true';
        } else {
            window.location.href = page + '?param=true';
        }
    } else {
        // dummy code to visualize result. Replace with something more useful
        let node = document.getElementById('output');
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode('param= true is set'))
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkParam()">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p id="output">"param = true" is missing from the URL</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code tries to avoid matching other params like 'someparam=true' and honors the presence of other parameters, if present by either appending with '?' or '&'